# SpringApplicationBuilder parent webapp and child without webapp doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext

I have a spring boot app with a parent application context and a child application context with some legacy code. I would like to have a webapp in the parent application context, and have the child context be a non webapp.

I have my config and properties in application.yml, that gets loaded in the main class

```
@ComponentScan(...)
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyApplication(
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApplication.class)
                    .profiles("Prod")
                    .web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
                    .listeners(new MainAppListener())  // logging for some of the events
                    .child(LegacyServiceConfig.class)
                    .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                    .listeners(new LegacyAppListener())  // logging for some of the events
                    .run(args);
    }
}
```

What I've tried so far:

1. I don't have any web application type config in my application.yml (`spring.main.web-application-type`). I hoped that the configuration I've specified thru code, in the above snippet would have worked, but it doesn't. Neither of the application contexts start as a webapp, effectively ignoring the config `web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)` in the above snippet.
2. I tried putting `spring.main.web-application-type=servlet` in my
   application.yaml. But that seems to apply this config to both parent
   and child application context. And both of them try to start as
   webapps, which is not what I want.

How do I get this to work? Any pointers?

Comment: Apparently, when calling `child` it will overwrite the `web` setting on the parent configuration (undocumented) and set it to `WebApplicationType.NONE`. It says this in the code: "It's not possible if embedded web server are enabled to support web contexts as parents because the servlets cannot be initialized at the right point in lifecycle.". The whole builder seems to be very unintuitive, and examples on the web seem to get it wrong more often than right. One way is to build and start the parent separately and pass it to each child you want.

Answer (score -2):

As per my knowledge in spring-boot start from main only and the main class is provided by Maven, because I had worked on Maven project. All the properties in the project like JDBC connection, port change you can do it in .properties(extension) type file. And this file can also be in format of .yml also. These file is totally different from main class.

If you make any changes in main or add any extra annotation in main then it will throw an error.

So keep every properties in .properties or .yml file and all configuration component scan in pom.xml file you can have two .properties file also

But main class should be simple like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication()
public class SpringBootProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but I'm not sure if this applies in my case.

Is there a way to define parent child hierarchies in application context using just a properties file ? or someway to have multiple properties files and have them wired in code via annotations (similar to the snipped in the question above? )